# A numerical calculation attempt

Tags: python, ipython, computer-science, precision, numerical-methods

I was reading [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com) today and I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592377/what-is-the-derivative-of-fx-x2x3x4x5x6x7x) question. Please take a look at the question and Brevan Ellefsen's answer.

The question asks about taking the derivative of `f(x)=x^(2*x^(3*x^(4*x^(5*x^(6*x^(7*x^(...)))))))` (looks like SO doesn't support LaTeX)

Brevan Ellefsen didn't really answer the question, but took a numerical approach to the function. Motivated from that answer, I tried to implement the function in Python. I don't have any experience in numerical methods but I really like these kind of coding.

So here is my code:

```
# Precision is set to 50.
def f(k, x):
    if (k < 1):
        # First argument cannot be less than one.
        return -1
    try:
        temp = 1
        for i in xrange(k):
            temp = (k-i)*(x**temp)
        return temp
    except TypeError:
        # k should be an integer.
        return -1
```

Now I'm calling the function for `k = 4` and `x = 0.5` and I'm comparing my function's output with WolframAlpha's output. Here are the results:

```
0.43854381197983005602480943707632832229137420654297 <-- My output
0.43854381197983004379857027951312617339018977615169 <-- WolframAlpha's output
```

As you can see, after some point, the ouputs are very different. It's not a very big difference but still enough to make me curious.

- Why is this happening?
  For this part, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) one is helpful and I've already seen it months ago, so I'm a little aware of floating number behaviour but I wasn't sure that was the reason in my case when I posted my question in the first place. I will still need help for the following ones anyway.
- Is my function not working properly?

  - If so, how should I fix it?
  - If it's OK, which result is more precise?
  - How can I optimize my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "Precision is set to 50."? How do you think you did that? There's no way to set Python's floating-point precision. (Also, 50 what?)

Comment: @user2357112 I was using Anaconda's Scientific Python Development Environment (namely Spyder) which has IPython integrated, and IPython has a _magic command_ `precision`. When I type, for instance, `precision 50`, it's set that the output will be up to 50 decimal numbers after the point.

Comment: That says "Set floating point precision **for pretty printing**". It doesn't actually give you more precision for computation; you need an arbitrary-precision math library for that. `gmpy` or the built-in `decimal` module would be reasonable choices.

Comment: @user2357112 So are you saying IPython's `precision` command is the reason for that difference?

Comment: No, the difference is because Wolfram Alpha is using arbitrary-precision math and you're not.